# Update vertx Json config file during http request

Tags: java, config, vert.x

I have VertX application with a config.json file. I want to edit one of the properties in the file during an HTTP request.

Is it possible?

**Json Config:**

```json
{
  "REQUEST_OPTIONS": {
    "dataFilter": [
      {
        "name": "xxx",
        "values": [1, 2, 3] -> want to edit this specific field!
      },
      {
        "name": "yyy",
        "values": [4, 5, 6]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Start method:**

```java
@Override
public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) {
    CompositeFuture.all(
            //Some other Futures ,
            Future.future(ConfigRetriever.create(vertx)::getConfig)
                    .flatMap(config -> storeData(config)
                            .compose(maybeStoreData -> CompositeFuture.all(
                                    matcherVerticle(subject).apply(maybeStoreData),
                                    http(sharedData, maybeStoreData).apply(config)
                            ))))
            .<Void>mapEmpty()
            .onComplete(startPromise);
```

**Router code:**

```java
router.get("/api/action").handler(performAction(configJson));
```

**Action request:**

```java
private Handler<RoutingContext> performAction(JsonObject config) {
    return routingContext -> Try.of(() -> Json.decodeValue(routingContext.getBody(), RequestDto.class))
            .onFailure(ex -> log.warn("Failed to process the RequestDto: ", ex))
            .andThen(requestDto -> ???UPDATE CONFIG FILE according to requestDto ???)
            .onFailure(ex -> log.warn("Failed to save request: ", ex))
            .onFailure(ex -> routingContext.response().setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.code()))
            .onSuccess(handler -> routingContext.response().setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.OK.code()));
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify, do you want to edit your JSON file or its memory representation that you have in `JsonObject`?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I wand to edit my file JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have your JsonObject already, you can write it to disk using `fileSystem().writeFile()`.

Here's a full example:

```java
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

var json = new JsonObject("{\n" +
        "  \"REQUEST_OPTIONS\": {\n" +
        "    \"dataFilter\": [\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"name\": \"xxx\",\n" +
        "        \"values\": [1, 2, 3]" +
        "      },\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"name\": \"yyy\",\n" +
        "        \"values\": [4, 5, 6]\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "    ]\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}");

json.copy()
    .getJsonObject("REQUEST_OPTIONS")
    // Accessing the dataFilter array
    .getJsonArray("dataFilter")
    // Getting the first element of dataFilter array
    .getJsonObject(0)
    // Accessing the values array
    .getJsonArray("values")
    .add(4);

vertx.fileSystem().writeFile("./new.json", json.toBuffer());
```